# are ms-dos api calls hard coded into exe?

Tags: caching, exe, dos

if i remember correctly, when dos loads a programm, the programm gets to use all of the processor, i.e. dos doesn't do anything in the meantime, but somehow that doesnt figure for me, i.e. api calls still have to be evaluated. are the api calls hard coded into the programm when an asm file is assembled and linked? the reason i want to know this, is that i need to know weather the cache is fully free for the exe, to experiment with cache optimization.

Comment: Doesn't API call stop your program? Also note that interrupts are still working.

Answer (score 3):

You remember right, DOS is single-tasked operating system. When your program runs, it gets full control over the processor.

The DOS API calls are made through the INT 21 interrupt. When you call an API function, the registers are loaded with appropriate parameters and the INT 21 interrupt is invoked. The control then gets back to the operating system, that processes the request and then passes the control back to your application.

The parameter setup and interrupt call I mentioned are linked in the executable statically, the is no dynamic loaded libraries.